# How to draw a block on others with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is the diagram I am trying to make using tikz. Blocks A, B and C are inside a block (here, block with red background) and blocks E and F are inside another block. The two huge blocks (with red background) have labels on top (LabA and LabB). Moreover, I would like block E to be right and in the middle of the blocks A and B. And arrows going to block E should have some bending angle; so, not like in the one I have tried.

[image: Expected]

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw=black, thick, text width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center]  
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \node[block] (a) {a};
        \node[block, below=of a, yshift=0.7cm] (b) {b};
        \node[block, below=of b, yshift=0.7cm] (c) {c};
        \node[block, right=of c, xshift=0.7cm] (d) {d};
        
        \node[block, right=of a, xshift=0.7cm, yshift=-0.4cm] (e) {e};
        
        \draw [arrow] (a) -- (e);
        \draw [arrow] (b) -- (e);
        \draw [arrow] (c) -- (d);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How could I add a rectangle over some nodes and write a label on top of it.
How to have the arrows here with a certain angle of inclination (not straight), and also to have the E block in the middle and in right of the A and B blocks. I though I could get the arrows with  `\draw [arrow] (a) -|- (e);`, but it does not work.

I have also added `\node[draw,inner xsep=4mm,inner ysep=7mm,fit=(a)(b)(c)]{};` but this produce the following error:

```
Timed out. Sorry, your compile took too long to run and timed out. This may be due to a LaTeX error, or a large number of high-res images or complicated diagrams.
```

Thank you in advance

[image: Current state]

Comment: Not related but you may refrain from using `tikzstyle` which is deprecated nowadays. Use `tikzset` instead. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: blocks onto blocks]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
        fit,
        backgrounds,
        positioning,
        calc,
        arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
        bBlock/.style={minimum width=5mm,fill=blue!70,text=white},
        rBlock/.style={minimum width=1cm,minimum height=3cm,fill=red},
        arr/.style={line width=.75pt,-Stealth}
        }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[on grid,font=\sffamily]
        \def\dist{1.5} % Distance between red blocks
        \node[bBlock] (A) {A};
        \node[bBlock,below of= A] (B) {B};
        \node[bBlock,below of=B] (C) {C};
        
        \path($(A)!0.5!(B)$)--++ (\dist,0) node[bBlock] (E) {E};
        \path(C)--++ (\dist,0) node[bBlock] (D) {D};
        
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \node[rBlock,fit=(A)(C),label=above:LabA] (R1) {};
            \node[rBlock,right= \dist cm of R1,label=above:LabB] (R2) {};
        \end{scope}
        
        \draw[arr] (A) --++ (.5*\dist,0) |- ($(E.west)+(0,0.1)$);
        \draw[arr] (B) --++ (.5*\dist,0) |- ($(E.west)+(0,-0.1)$);
        \draw[arr] (C) -- (D);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT: Some explanations

**1.** You have to define your blocks aspects with `tikzset`. Here I chose to set `minimum width` to 1cm for the red ones and to 0.5cm for the blue ones, then, in order to have two identical red blocks, I set the `minimum height`to 3 cm. Note that I defined the arrow style too.

**2.** The `on grid` parameter is here to define nodes *on grid*, i.e. when positioning a node right from another one, the node width does not affect the positioning.

**3.** `\path($(A)!0.5!(B)$)--++ (\dist,0)` means that you start from the middle point between nodes A and B (using `calc` library) then add `\dist`to the right to find the place where you put node E.

**4.** You have to draw and fill your red nodes on the background layer because you already drew your blue nodes. This can be achieved both with Excelsior command or mine. The left red node is defined fitting A and C nodes, then the right red node is defined to be placed on the right at `\dist` cm.

**5.** `\draw[arr] (A) --++ (.5*\dist,0) |- ($(E.west)+(0,0.1)$);` means that you draw an arrow starting from node A, going right on half the `\dist` (to go exactly in the middle of teh space between the two red nodes), then using `|-` you do the right angle, and go to node E. But you dont want the two arrows to end exactly at the same place, so here's another use of `calc` to end the arrow a bit above the `west` of node E (and the arrow coming from B, a bit below).

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Thank you so much @SebGlav. Could you please comment your code a bit ?

Comment: @Kyv I edited my post to let some explanations. Hope this is clear.

Comment: It is clear @SebGlav. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

**Q1** *How could I add a rectangle over some nodes and write a label on top of it.*

You can use the `fit` command, where you can fit a rectange around defined nodes for the rectangle. The drawback is, that the rectangle is lower for the second column, since the nodes are lower there. Alternatively, you can place a rectangle in the  background 'by hand'.

**Q2** *How to have the arrows here with a certain angle of inclination (not straight), and also to have the E block in the middle and in right of the A and B blocks.*

The arrows can be tuned using `--++(xshift,yshift)` syntax and then do the 'prependicular command' `|-`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc,backgrounds}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw=black, fill=cyan, thick, minimum height=0.5cm, align=center]  

\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \node[block] (a) {\textcolor{white}{A}} node[above=10pt] {\textbf{Lab A}};
        \node[block, below=of a, yshift=0.7cm] (b) {\textcolor{white}{B}};
        \node[block, below=of b, yshift=0.7cm] (c) {\textcolor{white}{C}};
        \node[block, right=of c, xshift=0.7cm] (d) {\textcolor{white}{D}};
        
        \node[block, right=of a, xshift=0.7cm, yshift=-0.4cm] (e) {\textcolor{white}{E}};
        
        \node[above=10pt] at (e) {\textbf{Lab B}};
        
        \draw [arrow] (a) --++ (1,0) |-  (e);
        \draw [arrow] (b) --++ (1,0) |- (e);
        \draw [arrow] (c) -- (d);
        
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \node[fit=(a)(c), fill=red, inner sep=5pt] {};
            \node[fit=(d)(e), fill=red, inner sep=5pt] {};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Excelsior

Answer (score 1):

With use of `backgrounds`, `calc`, `chains` and `fit` Ti*k*Z libraries for node positioning, and `arrows.meta` for arrows:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                calc, chains, 
                fit,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 8mm,
  start chain = going below,
   box/.style = {fill=blue!50, font=\bfseries, text=white,
                 minimum height=4ex, minimum width=1em,
                 outer sep=0pt},
   FIT/.style = {fill=red, inner sep=2mm, fit=#1},
every path/.append style = {draw, semithick, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}}
                        ]
%
\scoped[nodes={box, on chain}]
{
\node   (a) {A};   
\node   (b) {B};
\node   (c) {C};
}
%
\node [box, 
       right=of $(a.east)!0.5!(b.east)$] (e) {E};
\node [box,
       right=of c]                       (d) {D};
%
\scoped[on background layer]
{
    \node[FIT=(a) (c)] {};
    \node[FIT=(a.north -| e) (d)] {};
}
%
\draw   (a.east) --++ (4mm,0) |- ([yshift=+3pt] e.west);
\draw   (b.east) --++ (4mm,0) |- ([yshift=-3pt] e.west);
\draw   (c) -- (d);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All other answers use a fitting node drawn on background layer to fill the area surrounding a group of nodes.

As the group of nodes has a regular distribution, it's possible to draw them as a `matrix` node and fill the `matrix` with a different color from inner nodes. This way no `backgrounds` or `fitting` nodes are needed.

In this particular case, the distribution of nodes in right block is not so god for a `matrix`, but it's possible to solve the problem. As right lower block position is equivalent to left lower block, a similar matrix has been drawn, but with two upper blocks filled with background color. After that, an independent block is placed over the matrix.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={fill=blue!50, font=\bfseries, text=white,
        minimum size=4ex, inner sep=.3333em, outer sep=0pt},
    Box/.style={matrix of nodes, row sep=1mm, nodes in empty cells, fill=red, inner sep=1mm, 
        nodes={box, anchor=center}},
    link/.style={-Stealth, blue!50!black, thick}]
        
\matrix[Box] (B1) {|(A)|A\\|(B)|B\\|(C)|C\\};   

\matrix[Box, right=5mm of B1, nodes={fill=red}] (B2) {\\ \\|[name=D, fill=blue!50]|D\\};
\path (B2-1-1)--node[box] (E) {E} (B2-2-1); 

\draw[link] (A)--++(0:6mm)|-(E);
\draw[link] (B)--++(0:6mm)|-(E);
\draw[link] (C)--(D);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]